# Considerations on a problem of trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, education

I have this picture where the textbook of my students of 17 years old say to find the area of the quadrilater $AOBC$ (with $|AO|=|OB|=r$ the radius of the circle with the center in $O$), your perimeter and the area of mixtilinear triangle $\triangle ACB$ knowing that the angle $\angle ACB=\pi/3$. In particular the textbook say that to take two point on the circle $A$ and $B$ and to draw the straight tangent lines that they meet in a point $C$ forming an angle of $\angle ACB=\pi/3$.

[image]

The problem was solved in class but I made some considerations. If I draw everything with **Geogebra** or any other software I observe that the triangle $\triangle ABC$ is equilater: in fact $CH$ cut $AB$ in two equal parts and the median $CH$ is also the bisector of the angle $\angle ACB$. Hence $\angle CBH=\angle BAC=\pi/3$.

> If I would have drawn the triangle wrongly, with an angle of $\pi/3$ and didn't notice that it is an equilateral triangle, is there a quick way to prove it?

Trying to be rigorous if I have two tangent lines to the circumference, at two points $AB$ and $B$ that, intersected, form an angle of $\pi/3$, how do I guess that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral? If the angle had been any other amplitude it might as well have been isosceles or scalene.

I have thought to use a circle to center $O(0,0)$ and radius $r$

$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$ and $$\tan \angle ACB=\frac{\pi}3=\left|\frac{m-m'}{1+mm'}\right|$$ where $m$ it is the slope of the tangent in the point $A$ and $m'$ in the point $B$, but I not know the coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Triangles $CAO$ and $CBO$ are equal, hence $CA=CB$. And then, base angles of an isosceles triangle are equal, hence...

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Yes of course triangle $CAO$ is rectangular since the tangent is perpendicular to the radius. The same is true for triangle $CBO$. I could have an angle in $C$ that is 20° and the angle $CAH$ that is 70°, but I don't have an equilateral triangle but a scalene one.

Comment: Of course you have an equilateral triangle only if $\angle ACB=60°$, I'm afraid I don't understand your remark.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca In this morning I have drawn the measure incorrectly triangle $ABC$ that visually, even if the angle is $\pi/3$, the oblique sides $AC$ and $BC$ of the triangle were not congruent.

Comment: See my answer: I hope it is clear.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Totally clear :-). In fact I have put +1 :-) I hope to have understood me :-) for the comment: "In this morning....".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangles $$ and $$ are equal by hypotenuse-leg congruence, hence $=$.
But base angles of an isosceles triangle are equal, hence:
$$
\angle CAB=\angle CBA ={180°-60°\over2}=60°.
$$